# xdebug instantly timeouts, though host IDE is listening

Tags: php, timeout, xdebug

Trying to debug remotely over openVPN, php 5.3.3, selinux disabled, local win firewall disabled.

Here is snippet from xdebug debugging log:

```
Log opened at 2014-10-14 20:35:03 
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 10.113.255.38:9000. 
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-( 
Log closed at 2014-10-14 20:35:04

^C
```

and right after this:

```
[root@mn httpd]# telnet 10.113.255.38 9000 
Trying 10.113.255.38...
Connected to 10.113.255.38. 
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So IDE(PHPCharm) actually listening for external connections.  Here is xdebug.ini:

```html
zend_extension='/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so' 
;xdebug.remote_host=10.113.255.38 
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug-debug.log 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200 
xdebug.remote_enable=1 xdebug.idekey='PP'
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

What might be the problem? Any hints highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the server inside your local network or not? Or maybe a firewall inside your local network? And: what timeout is configured inside the xdebug configuration?

Comment: Server not inside my local network, I'm trying to access it via VPN. I'm not aware about any firewalls in the middle. telnet connection goes through successfully, as shown in the post. I didn't configure any xdebug timouts, afaik there is no such setting in xdebug. :(